# Перестала работать функция при переходе на новую версию Delphi 10.2.3

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-10-tokyo

Есть функция

```
uses
  ..., CommCtrl;

...

function GetSysListView32_x64(AList: TStrings): Boolean;
var
  i, ItemCount: Integer;
  Buf: array[0..255] of Char;
  PID, ProcessHandle, Dummy: DWORD;
  pCh: PChar;
  pItem: PLVItem64;
  Item: TLVItem64;
  hProcess: THandle;
  sL: TStrings;
begin
  Result := False;

  hProcess := FindWindow(nil, 'Г„ГЁГ±ГЇГҐГІГ·ГҐГ° Г§Г*Г¤Г*Г· Windows');
  hProcess := FindWindowEx(hProcess, 0, nil, 'ГЏГ°Г®Г¶ГҐГ±Г±Г»');
  hProcess := FindWindowEx(hProcess, 0, 'SysListView32', nil);
  if hProcess = 0 then Exit;

  GetWindowThreadProcessID(hProcess, @PID);
  ProcessHandle := OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, False, PID);
  if ProcessHandle = 0 then Exit;

  pCh := VirtualAllocEx(ProcessHandle, nil, 255, MEM_COMMIT,  PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
  pItem := VirtualAllocEx(ProcessHandle, nil, SizeOf(TLVItem64), MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
  ItemCount := ListView_GetItemCount(hProcess);

  sL := TStringList.Create;
  try

for i := 0 to ItemCount - 1 do
begin
  Item.mask := LVIF_TEXT;
  Item.iItem := i;
  Item.iSubItem := 0;
  Item.pszText := Int64(pCh);
  Item.cchTextMax := SizeOf(Buf);

  WriteProcessMemory(ProcessHandle, pItem, @Item, SizeOf(TLVItem64), Dummy);
  SendMessage(hProcess, LVM_GETITEMTEXT, i, LPARAM(pItem));
  ReadProcessMemory(ProcessHandle, pCh, @Buf, 255, Dummy);

  sL.Add(Format('%.3d - %s', [i, Buf]));
end;

AList.Text := sL.Text;

  finally
    sL.Free;
    VirtualFreeEx(ProcessHandle, pCh, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
    VirtualFreeEx(ProcessHandle, pItem, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
    CloseHandle(ProcessHandle);
  end;

  Result := True;
end;
```

При компиляции стал выдавать ошибки:

> [dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(96): E2033 Types of actual and formal var parameters must be identical
>   [dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(98): E2033 Types of actual and formal var parameters must be identical

Ошибочные строки:

```
WriteProcessMemory(ProcessHandle, pItem, @Item, SizeOf(TLVItem64), Dummy);
...
ReadProcessMemory(ProcessHandle, pCh, @Buf, 255, Dummy);
```

Comment: Использую XE 10.2.3, а до этого использовал от очень старую еще от Бордланда

Comment: дак и приведите типы передаваемых параметров в полное соответствие сигнатуре метода.

Comment: @teran И как это сделать?

Comment: ну  у вас же там всего один `var`-параметр. Какой он счас там в сигнатуре просит, `SIZE_T` ? а передаете что? `dword`?  замените тип переменной `dummy` на нужный

Comment: @teran изменил тип на System.UInt64 - ничего не поменялось

Comment: интересно даже узнать, откуда вы взяли `uint64`

Comment: @teran из справки о функции

Comment: UInt64@ требуется...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У переменной `Dummy` (выходной параметр) тип должен быть `SIZE_T`, а не `DWORD`.

В Delphi 10.2 (`Winapi.Windows.pas`) он объявлен как `SIZE_T = ULONG_PTR` (а `ULONG_PTR = NativeUInt`).

Объявление функций (в том же юните) выглядит вот так:

```
function WriteProcessMemory(hProcess: THandle; const lpBaseAddress: Pointer; lpBuffer: Pointer;
  nSize: SIZE_T; var lpNumberOfBytesWritten: SIZE_T): BOOL; stdcall;

function ReadProcessMemory(hProcess: THandle; const lpBaseAddress: Pointer; lpBuffer: Pointer;
  nSize: SIZE_T; var lpNumberOfBytesRead: SIZE_T): BOOL; stdcall;
```